# ADODB - why is my recordset read-only?

Tags: excel, vba, adodb, recordset

In Excel, I'm using ADODB connection to build a recordset, fetching data from the worksheet in its own workbook as following:

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim k As Variant

    cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
       "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1;Readonly=False"";"

    strSQL = "SELECT F1 FROM [Workbench$];"

    rst.Open strSQL, cnn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
    rst.MoveFirst

    While Not rst.EOF
        rst("F1") = "NewValue"
        rst.Update
        rst.MoveNext
    Wend

End Sub
```

However, an error occurs while I run the code:

> Run-time error '-2147217911 (80040e09)':
>       Cannot update. Database or object is read-only.

I have checked about permission of my opened workbook and it is ok (Full Control access for everyone).

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: Try replacing adOpenStatic with adOpenDynamic.

Answer (score 5):

I fixed my problem by Use IMEX=0

Comment: This worked for a SharePoint ADO connection when trying to add/update list items according to [this](https://scottlyerly.wordpress.com/2014/05/14/excel-geeking-using-vba-and-ado-to-pull-data-from-sharepoint-lists/) article.

Answer (score 0):

```
rst.Open strSQL, cnn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
```

replace to

```
rst.Open strSQL, cnn, 1, 3
```