# Update Excel worksheet using ADODB from external application

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

I've found lots of posts on this problem, but so far no solutions have helped.

I'd like to read and write data from/to an Excel worksheet from an external VBA application - so far it reads OK, but I get an error while trying to write values to the ADODB Recordset.

Here's the code:

```
Sub UpdateFromExcel()
'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15620080/reading-data-using-oledb-from-opened-excel-file

Dim oConn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim oRS As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim sPath
Dim sSQL As String

sSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A1:N10000]"
sPath = frmExcelSync.txtFilePath

oConn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & sPath & "';" & _
             "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1';"

oRS.Open sSQL, oConn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic


Do While Not oRS.EOF
    'ITERATE THROUGH EACH ROW HERE
    
    'ADD CODE ABOVE
    
'****GET AN ERROR HERE:****
    oRS.Update "Occurrence Name", "Test"
    oRS.MoveNext
Loop

oRS.Close
oConn.Close

End Sub
```

The error is

> "Cannot update. Database or object is read-only".

I've tried different lock and cursor types, and I've tried editing the fields then using the `.update` method, but nothing has worked so far.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure if this helps: Try `IMEX=0` - See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14080591/adodb-why-is-my-recordset-read-only

Comment: hi, I tried this and it didn't help

Comment: I should mention that the `EditMode` property of the `oRS` object is set to `adEditNone`. This appears to be a read-only property, so I can't change it.

Answer (score 1):

your update statement is not correct. I believe you want to update the column "Occurrence Name" with the value "Test"

What you should write is.

```
Do While Not oRS.EOF
    oRS![Occurrence Name].value = "Test"


     oRS.MoveNext
    Loop

oRS.Update
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this and it didn't help - I got the same error.

Comment: Can you check the value of the recordset after the line when setting it to "Test"? I believe your problem is the fact that it is a select from a sheet, not a DB. so it will update the recordset but you will need to push it back to the sheet by updating the cells..

Comment: Refer to my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to have gone away somehow.
I tried a few different things (different spreadsheets) with mixed success then restarted the application - now it works.

No code changes at all.